# Kotlin: handling exception when defining a val

Tags: kotlin, exception

I'm working on a kotlin web backend and have something like this:

```
try {
    val uuid = UUID.fromString(someString)
} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    throw BadRequestException("invalid UUID")
}

doSomething(uuid)
```

The code above doesn't compile since `uuid` is unresolved outside the `try` block.

Alternatives I can imagine are:

- move `doSomething(uuid)` inside the try block, but I'd rather avoid that so I don't accidentally catch some other potential `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by `doSomething` (if that happens for whatever reason I want things to fail and get a 500 in my logs so I can investigate)
- use a nullable `var` instead and initialize it to null but that seems a bit ugly?

This `throw BadRequestException` pattern is working well otherwise so I don't want to change the return type of the method or something like that in order to avoid throwing.

Is there a better / more elegant / recommended pattern for this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin, try/catch can be used as an expression. Branches that throw don't affect the resolved type. So you can write:

```
val uuid = try {
    UUID.fromString(someString)
} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    throw BadRequestException("invalid UUID")
}
```